# Crossing the Skadar Lake by boat or bicycle

Tags: montenegro, albania, balkans, lakes

I will be making a trip to Skadar Lake from the Montenegrin side. I searched a lot to find out if there are any services that take you to the Albanian side as well.

I know that I can visit the Albanian side from the town called Shkoder for which I need to take a bus or taxi from places like Kotor or Podgorica. However, I would just like to cross the lake from one side to the other and get back if possible. Is there any way to do that?

Also, I would like to know if there are any bicycle routes where I can make a round trip of the lake, touching both Montenegro and Albania.

Comment: I quite liked Shkoder. If time allows, I'd consider staying there for a night. No idea about crossing the lake, but you may have issues finding customs and immigration if you don't go by road.

Answer (score 3):

**By Boat**

There are no boat services available that cross the lake from Montenegro to Albania, there are only boat tours available.

**By Bike**

There is a route round the lake but it is around 130 km long:

[image]

Comment: Daniil, is the 'lack of ferries' now during COVID 19 times or is this the 'usual' situation?

Comment: @Willeke it's usual, no ferries operate at any time

Comment: @Willeke There are no maritime border control facilities at the lake